# Draw a rectangle with semi-transparent border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, borders

I have a fairly simple image:

[image]

I'd like to change it to be wider at the ends like below, while still keeping the nice rounded shape:

[image]

The shape has solid gray colour, but its border is kindof *transparent* giving it a nice smooth finish, which I need to keep (**as exact as it possible**):

[image]

I think modifying this shape would distort the border, so I might have to redraw it, which seem an easy task with *rounded rectangle*. I just don't have an idea about the border, please give me some hints on that.

Reacting to comments (thank you!):

This is the original one's anti-aliasing:

[image]

I draw a rounded rectangle the way I want and anti-aliasing seems existing only on the rounded parts, and not on top and bottom straight lines:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you rescale/resize/resample/stretch/distort a raster image, the image quality will degrade. In Photoshop, it's probably better to use a vector shape if you think you might want to alter it later.  BTW, the semi-transparent border you are referring to is called "anti-aliasing". To be honest, I would advise you not to use Photoshop for work like this. Use a vector image editor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "border" is merely anti-aliasing.

Draw a vector shape.. export or save it to a raster format, the anti-aliasing will be introduced.

You could also use the Shape Tools to draw a raster/pixel shape and the anti-aliasing will be introduced the moment you let go of the mouse.

Comment: I drew a shape (with shape tools), exported to PNG, but AA is not visible on the straight top and bottom edges. (See my update pls)

Comment: @Daniel thats just because your snapping to the pixel grid if your shape is nudged 0.5 px up or right the situation is different

Comment: @Daniel, AA isn't normally needed on vertical and horizontal lines. They don't have that problem of looking jagged as they follow the pixel grid perfectly. If you blur those lines the whole shape will look slightly out of focus and if you don't they have a slightly different look than the curves. One of the dilemmas of pixel rendering.